# Is is bad design for a parent class's method in Python to produce instances of its children?

Tags: python, oop, python-3.x, inheritance, design-patterns

I am doing some work with the Wikipedia category graph (using Python 3.5), and have run into a design problem.

I have a base class Page, which defines some methods common to both articles and categories, as well as classes for Article and Category, which inherit from Page.

The problem is that each of these classes are quite large, so ideally I'd like them in separate modules within a package. However, since any page on Wikipedia (i.e. both articles and categories) can itself have categories, the method to return the categories of a page is defined in the base Page class. This means that the Page class depends on Category. However, since Category depends on Page, this is a circular dependency so the only way it will work without scoped imports is by defining both Category and Page in the same module.

This really comes down to the fact that a method of the base class produces instances of a specific child thereof, which is not a pattern I've had cause to use before. (As opposed to a base class generically producing instances of whichever child is calling the method). Is there a design pattern that will deal with this situation, or is this perhaps one of the rare cases that calls for a scoped import?

Snippet below for a vague illustration:

```
class Page(object):

    def categories(self):
        return [Category(title) for title in self._category_titles()]

class Category(Page):
    ...
```

Comment: You don't need a scoped import. You only need `Category` to exist when `Page().categories()` is used. So an `import category_module` is *enough* here, then use `category_module.Category()` in your code.

Comment: Generally speaking, yes, it's bad, because it break [encapsulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28computer_programming%29). There's another advanced OOP idiom called "virtual contrcutors" which can do something sort of like this (invented by James Coplien), but it's unclear to me if that would help here. Perhaps the problem is with your class hierarchy itself. Maybe `Page` and `Category` just need to share a common base class (which might be abstract and never be instantiated itself).

Comment: @MartijnPieters - thanks, that does indeed work. I didn't realise that would work differently from `from .category import Category` but I guess I need to read a little more about the import process mechanics.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with circular dependency hints that the classes are actually tightly coupled, so it is better to keep them in the same module.

In my opinion you just trying to solve the problem, which is "these classes are quite large" in a wrong way. Python modules are used to group related classes / functions together, which is your case.

On the other hand, problem with [large classes](https://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/smells/large-class) should be solved by refactoring them into smaller classes / functions.